# How to get my score counter working in a SpriteKit game

Tags: sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit and Xcode to make a game and the counter is 'counting' but it only updates at the end of the game when you start a new one.

```
func adjustScore(by points: Int) {
    score += points
}
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile: SKSpriteNode, monster: SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Hit")

    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()

    monstersDestroyed += 1
    adjustScore(by: 100)

    if monstersDestroyed > 30 {
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontal(withDuration: 0.5)
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: true)
        view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: reveal)
    }
```

Where have I gone wrong?

answer solved but heres what is after my View Did Load:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        background.zPosition = -1
        background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
        addChild(background)

        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        scoreLabel.text = "Points = \(score)"
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 20
        scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.black
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/6.2, y: size.height/1.2)
        addChild(scoreLabel)

        HighScoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        HighScoreLabel.text = "High score = \(highScore)"
        HighScoreLabel.fontSize = 20
        HighScoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.black
        HighScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/5.2, y: size.height/6)
        addChild(HighScoreLabel)

        NewSkinLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
        NewSkinLabel.text = ""
        NewSkinLabel.fontSize = 20
        NewSkinLabel.fontColor = SKColor.black
        NewSkinLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/4.4)
        addChild(NewSkinLabel)
}
```

Comment: Where is the code to show the score? In the code you listed the score increases, but there is no code that shows the score.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk earlier in the GameScene there is code that shows the score in  a label, would it be helpful for me to post that as-well?

Comment: Yes. Post the code that shows the score. Also look at Alexandru's answer. It's probably the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Could you post the code of your `didSet` function and the code that declares the global `scoreLabel` variable? The link to your Github code was removed in an edit. Posting that code will provide context for my answer so it makes more sense to someone who comes across this question.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I cant find a didset function within the game scene?

Comment: Sorry, I meant didMove, the function that sets up the scene where you set up the local scoreLabel variable. Post the code I talked about in my answer so the answer makes sense. Right now someone reading this question and my answer would have no way of knowing what is going on due to the GitHub link being removed.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I think I've done what you were asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. First, you never access `scoreLabel` outside of  `didMove` so the score label never changes. You have to write code to update the score label, as Alexandru demonstrated in his answer.

Your second problem is that you have two `scoreLabel` variables, a global var and a local `scoreLabel` let constant in the `didMove` function.  When you declare `scoreLabel` in `didMove`,

```
let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
scoreLabel.text = "Total Coins: \(score)"
scoreLabel.fontSize = 40
scoreLabel.fontColor = SKColor.black
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/1.5)
addChild(scoreLabel)
```

This version of `scoreLabel` goes away when you exit `didMove`. Now if you access the global `scoreLabel` to display the score, the label is empty. You loaded and set everything on the temporary local version.

The easiest way to fix this issue and avoid confusion is to have only one `scoreLabel` variable. Get rid of the global `scoreLabel` and declare `scoreLabel` as a property of the `GameScene` class. Then in `didMove`, remove the let to load `scoreLabel`.

```
scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
```

Now the value of `scoreLabel` will stay around when the scene finishes loading. If you update `scoreLabel` in `adjustScore`, the score should update.

One more thing. If you have a response about things not working, you need to provide more information than "I tried this and it didn't work." That is not a helpful response. You have to describe what didn't work or else there will be a lot of back and forth trying to get the relevant information, increasing the time it takes for you to get the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When the projectile hits a monster, you update the score, but you don't update the label. In this case, the label will always be equal to the initial value that you set at the start of your game

When you increment the score, you should also update the `score_label`.

```
func adjustScore(by points: Int) 
{
    score += points
    score_label.text = "Points = \(score)"
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work, I'll add a link to the source code so you can see the project (there's a lot of stuff going on which i think could stop the label updating)